# How to set xlim in multhist?

Tags: r

The following code creates 3 vectors, and displays them as interlaced histograms:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,1,2)
c <- c(1,1,1)
l <- list(a,b,c)

multhist(l, col=c("red","green","blue"),xlim=c(0,5))
```

However, when I specify this xlim=c(0,5), I would expect this to set the x axis range, but it does not seem to do so. The x-axis appears to only range between about 1.0 and 1.4. Is there a different way to specify the x-axis range for a multhist?

Comment: Please specify either the package or the code for the multhist function.

Comment: This is probably closely related to your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9767758/420055), which also calls for custom settings in a dedicated plotting function (from [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html)?).

Comment: Yes, this multhist function is from plotrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not perfect, but a start:

**edit**: remove x-axis labels, add box

```
multhist(l, col=c("red","green","blue"),
  breaks=seq(0,5,by=0.2),names.arg=rep("",25))
box(bty="l")  ## add box around bottom and left edges
```

`multhist` is a bit of a hack (I know, I wrote it!) -- it uses `barplot` internally, so the x axis is indexing the positions of the bars rather than the actual values.

See also

- http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/multhist.pdf
- http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/multhist.Rnw

for some other ideas about how to display binned data from multiple groups.

Comment: Yep, that seems to do the trick. Now I want to turn off the axes labels (because they are awkward values like .1, .5, .9, etc). I tried: 
multhist(l, col=c("red","green","blue"),breaks=seq(0,5,by=0.2), ann=FALSE)
but they still seem to be displayed?

Comment: I also tried this multhist(data, axes=FALSE), but the vertical axis is gone but there are still some strange lines and number on the x-axis. http://daviddoria.com/Uploads/multhist.png Ideally I would want the vertical and horizontal axes both drawn, but without tickmarks or numbers on either.