# Specifying colors to multhist

Tags: r

I would like to use multhist from the plotrix library to plot interlaced histograms. I need to specify the colors of each of these histograms. I tried this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,1,2)
c <- c(1,1,1)
l <- list(1,b,c)
mycolors <- list("red", "green", "blue")
multhist(l, col=mycolors)
```

but it doesn't like the way I have specified the colors. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Turns out it is as easy as this: multhist(l, col=c("red","green","blue"))

Comment: Various things: 1 This belongs on stackoverflow. 2 You can answer your own question and then accept it. 3 You are missing the line `l <- list(1,b,c)`

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is as easy as this

```
multhist(l, col=c("red","green","blue"))
```